# Connecing to MapR database from Delphi/C++Builder app

Tags: delphi, c++builder, mapr

I'm trying to find out if there is something like [FireDac](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/firedac) or [dbExpress](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/DbExpress_Framework) to connect an application written in Delphi or C++ Builder to a [MapR](https://mapr.com/products/mapr-db/) Database. I was able to find [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Database_Connectivity_(FireDAC)) page that describes how to connect to various databases including **Teradata**, but there is no mention of **MapR**.
If anyone has done this, I would really appreciate any pointers you might be able to give me.

Comment: Looks like there is a REST api for [MapR](https://mapr.com/docs/61/MapR-DB/JSON_DB/UsingMapRDBJSONRESTAPI.html).

Comment: thanks @MartynA. I didn't know about the REST api, but I knew They have [C API](https://mapr.com/blog/high-performance-c-apis-mapr-db/). I was hoping I would not have to go to that level and have something like [FireDac](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/firedac).

Comment: Well, you're out of luck with FireDAC.  If you don't fancy REST, how about access via [ODBC](https://www.progress.com/odbc/mapr-hive?&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=dci-trial-search-dsa&gclid=Cj0KCQiAuf7fBRD7ARIsACqb8w6K3lyUkCo8SYAix2FldwCMu5GYbmVFnZ-RPXv53EXytyFSZ6UVyO8aAi2REALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)?  Depends where your MapR db is, I suppose ...

Comment: @MartynA [ODBC](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Hive+ODBC+Connector) would work Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FireDAC does not natively support MapR nor does dbExpress.

Your options seem to be:

1. Use MapR's REST Api - see [REST](https://mapr.com/docs/61/MapR-DB/JSON_DB/UsingMapRDBJSONRESTAPI.html)  or just google

   mapr rest api
2. Use ODBC access.  There is one available here: [HiveODBC](https://www.progress.com/odbc/mapr-hive?&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=dci-trial-search-dsa&gclid=Cj0KCQiAuf7fBRD7ARIsACqb8w6K3lyUkCo8SYAix2FldwCMu5GYbmVFnZ-RPXv53EXytyFSZ6UVyO8aAi2REALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).